# open IntelliJ IDEA14.1 failed

Tags: intellij-idea

the version Ultimate Edition 14.1,on mac;it always show the follow image when open it,

```
at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:178)
at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1$1.run(MainImpl.java:62)`enter code here`
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:676)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:674)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:685)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:362)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.FlatWelcomeFrame$FlatWelcomeScreen.c(FlatWelcomeFrame.java:312)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.FlatWelcomeFrame$FlatWelcomeScreen.a(FlatWelcomeFrame.java:226)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.FlatWelcomeFrame$FlatWelcomeScreen.<init>(FlatWelcomeFrame.java:215)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.FlatWelcomeFrame.<init>(FlatWelcomeFrame.java:78)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.FlatWelcomeFrameProvider.createFrame(FlatWelcomeFrameProvider.java:29)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.WelcomeFrame.showNow(WelcomeFrame.java:169)`enter code here`
at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication$IdeStarter.main(IdeaApplication.java:302)
at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:172)
... 16 more
```

Comment: Your stack trace is cut off at the top.

Comment: I still can't resolve it,any ideas,thanks!!